# Why does the div stretch correctly but not image?

Tags: html, css, image

I am new to HTML/CSS and curious why div stretch correctly in below example, but not image?

- Is the image calculated differently than div?
- Is there an MDN documentation i can read more about this behavior?

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  padding: 32px;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px -32px 0px -32px;
}

.gooddiv {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px -32px 0px -32px;
  border: 2px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img alt="SG Image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508964942454-1a56651d54ac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1035&q=80" />
  <div class="gooddiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: an image is different from a div. It's a replaced element with an intrinsic ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `<div>`, a `width: auto` setting will mean 100% of its parent element, so it will stretch.

For an image, `width: auto` (which is also the default if you don't define `width` at all) will mean that (unless there is a `height` setting) the image is displayed at its original size and therefore not stretch or shrink. If you define `width: 100%` or similar (or a height setting) , it will adjust.

I want to add that if an image is stretched beyond its original proportions, it will look distorted and have a bad quality, so it really wouldn't make sense to stretch an image by default to the size of its parent element, which might easily be larger than the image itself.

To avoid the mentioned distortion due to stretching beyond original size, a common way to handle that is to use `max-width: 100%;` (and also `max-height: 100%` if you defined height for the parent), thereby leaving `width` and `height` at their default `auto` (= original size). That way you'll stretch the image to full width if its at least as wide as the parent originally, or have it displayed at original size if its smaller (avoiding bad quality due to stretching beyond original size). In the snippet below, I only used `max-width: 100%;` (i.e. everything else at default settings), which limits the image width to the parent element width (minus padding), avoids stretching beyond original width and adjusts the height automatically, keeping the original height/width ratio. (BTW. I erased the negative margins you added, which wouldn't make sense in this context)

Note: Setting `width: 100%` *and*  `height: 100%` is *not* a good idea for images since in most cases this will distort the height/width proportion of the picture, making it look bad (unless it's an abstract graphic pattern where a disproportion between height and width doesn't matter).

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  padding: 32px;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.gooddiv {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px -32px 0px -32px;
  border: 2px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img alt="SG Image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508964942454-1a56651d54ac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1035&q=80" />
  <div class="gooddiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Furthermore, the card component is full screen. If you give at the img width:100% the image will be full screen too and it exists sreens 2500 pixel and more wide, thus you could set max-width:100%  or control the card width

Comment: so i did set the width and height both to 100%, but the image didn't stretch like the div did. Reading at Temani's comment i see it is replaced element, so seems it is layed out differently than html built in elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

Comment: please note the additions to my answer